# Move SignalR Hubs to Another Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to know is it possible to put **SignalR's** `Hub`(s) in a different project than **Asp.Net** project? If it's yes. How can I access to a `Hub` classes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean self hosting? If so check this: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware, it is not possible to put a SignalR Hub in anything other than an ASP.NET project, seeing that SignalR is built on the ASP.NET framework, and lives within the ASP.NET namespace. I have not found anything to say anything to the contrary.

However, since Hubs do not need to be in the same project to be **accessible** for clients, any .NET or Java-Script client can connect to the Hub with the proper amount of configuration.

This link explains how a JavaScript client works:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

If your not using a .NET client to connect, but, say, an external website, tone-in to the Cross-Site Reference section:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain

This links explains how a .NET Client such as a Windows Store App, Silverlight, WPF, and console applications work:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#clientsetup

Seeing as your trying to access a hub in a separate project, which isn't ASP.NET, I would suspect your using a .NET client of some form. The prior link explains how to configure those connections.

So, for example, if your building an .NET client, such as a Windows Store App, it can still access the SignalR Hub located in a ASP.NET project when published, allowing for any real-time functions to work in the client just as it would if the client was within the same ASP.NET project.